# How do I convert the following xaml statement to code?

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

Similar questions were asked many times, but I cannot quite make them work. How would I create C# version of the following xalm statement:

```
        <h:TubeVisual3D x:Name="PipeVisual" Path="{Binding Pipe.Path}" 
                        TextureCoordinates="{Binding Pipe.TextureCoordinates}"
                        Diameter="{Binding ElementName=PipeDiamSlider, Path= Value }" 
                        Material="{Binding Pipe.Material}"
                        BackMaterial="{Binding Pipe.Material}"
                        ThetaDiv="50" IsPathClosed="False"
                        Visible="{Binding ElementName=PipeIsVisibleCheck, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

Where “TubeVisual3D” is a 3D WPF element defined in Helix Toolkit and most of the parameters bound by the binding are dependency properties in “TubeVisual3D”.

Comment: What have you tryed so far and which errors did you get?

Comment: Your question is too broad and has too few details to give you an answer. Have you tried `var pv = new TubeVisual3D(); pv.Name="PipeVisual";` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to your markup would be this:

```
HelixToolkit.Wpf.TubeVisual3D pipeVisual = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.TubeVisual3D();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(pipeVisual, HelixToolkit.Wpf.ExtrudedVisual3D.PathProperty, new Binding("Pipe.Path"));
BindingOperations.SetBinding(pipeVisual, HelixToolkit.Wpf.ExtrudedVisual3D.TextureCoordinatesProperty, new Binding("Pipe.TextureCoordinates"));
BindingOperations.SetBinding(pipeVisual, HelixToolkit.Wpf.TubeVisual3D.DiameterProperty, new Binding("Value") { Source = PipeDiamSlider });
BindingOperations.SetBinding(pipeVisual, HelixToolkit.Wpf.MeshElement3D.MaterialProperty, new Binding("Pipe.Material"));
BindingOperations.SetBinding(pipeVisual, HelixToolkit.Wpf.MeshElement3D.BackMaterialProperty, new Binding("Pipe.Material"));
pipeVisual.ThetaDiv = 50;
pipeVisual.IsPathClosed = false;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(pipeVisual, HelixToolkit.Wpf.MeshElement3D.VisibleProperty, new Binding("IsChecked") { Source = PipeIsVisibleCheck });
```